# Share an enum between ASMX Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, webservice-client

I have a web service project with several web services. Two of this web services share an enum that is defined in a BL class, like so:

```
public class HumanResourcesService
{
    public SomeLibrary.Employee GetEmployee(int employeeCode)
    {
       var employee = new SomeLibrary.Employee();
       employee.Type= SomeLibrary.EmployeeType.SomeType;
       return employee ;
    }
}

public class BankService
{
    public bool ProcessPayment(int employeeCode, EmployeeType employeeType)
    {
        bool processed = false;
        // Boring code
        return processed;
    }
}
```

*This is just an example.*

Both web services, when referenced in a web project, generate a different `EmployeeType` enum proxies, so I need to cast explicitly to invoke the `ProcessPayment` method in `BankService`:

```
public void SomeMethod(int employeeCode)
{
     var hrService = new HumanResourcesService();
     var employee = hrService.GetEmployee(employeeCode);

     var bankService = new BankService();
     bankService.ProcessPayment(employee.Code, (MyProject.BankService.EmployeeType) employee.Type);
}
```

I understand .NET has to do this in order to create the WSDL, but can't I somehow make both services refer to the same enum on the proxy classes without breaking anything?

Comment: Are you using WCF or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sharetypes parameter of wsdl.exe. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you expose the same enum, the proxies will work fine:

```
public class BankService
{
    public bool ProcessPayment(int employeeCode, MyProject.BankService.EmployeeType employeeType)
    {
        bool processed = false;
        // Boring code
        return processed;
    }
}

public void SomeMethod(int employeeCode)
{
     var hrService = new HumanResourcesService();
     var employee = hrService.GetEmployee(employeeCode);

     var bankService = new BankService();
     bankService.ProcessPayment(employee.Code, employee.Type);
}
```

Comment: I do expose the same enum, defined in a common library.